# Dumping threads' Log Data into Common buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, synchronization

My program has different threads and one common logging thread will be running.

All my threads have to dump some logging data into a buffer in logging thread. The logging thread in-turn will write into log file once the buffer reaches some size.

How can i write into the common buffer without affecting the performance of the running threads.? I am thinking of some way without much overhead instead of using mutex or any other sync mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the performance penalties of using a mutex are low enough that it's just not worth the hassle of trying to make a Multi-producer, single consumer queue.  However [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918401/does-a-multiple-producer-single-consumer-lock-free-queue-exist-for-c) asks about such things and there are a few suggestions provided.